# Where to specify database credentials for MySQL cluster on Amazon OpsWorks?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I am migrating our Ruby On Rails app from DigitalOcean to Amazon OpsWorks. I created a MySQL layer and I've got root password to the database (+ I specified database name).
After deploying the application on the OpsWorks platform the app is running; though - in the `config/database.yml` are the "old" (different) credentials for MySQL installed on the DigitalOcean server.

In other words, in `config/database.yml` are not set credentials for the OpsWorks server, but the app and database is running - does it mean that OpsWorks ignore (/doesn't need it) what is set in `config/database.yml` or the fact the app is running is just a happy coincidence?

Comment: can you access the database form the terminal like this :>mysql -uroot ... without passing the "p"  password option..e.g >mysql -uroot p ...If yes, then you db is set to be accesed with no password.

Comment: OpsWorks would override an existing `database.yml` in a Rails App with the setting from the RDS Layer. Do you just assume that the `database.yml` was not changed, because you didn't set the new credentials? Or did you actually log into your server and check the content of the `database.yml` in the deploy directory?

Comment: @spickermann thanks for the answer. I assumed because I deployed the app and realised that the I forgot to set the new correct credentials, but the app was interacting with the databases properly, so it has been probably overwritten. Thanks!